# Break out of inner loop in Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

My question is how can we break out of an inner loop but still iterate to the next value when that loop is entered again.

Is it possbile?

Consider the below, extremely simplified, snippet:

```
item=['I','want','this','output']
i=[1,2,3,4]

for x in i:
    for y in item:
        print y
        break
```

The output is of course, 4 times the word 'I'

What I really want the output to be is this: 'I want this output'

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried inserting some debug print statements to better unterstand your algorithm?

Comment: You cannot interrupt the outer loop without also affecting the inner.

Comment: Maybe you need to rephrase/rethink your question a bit. Are you trying to pair up each corresponding item from your two lists?

Comment: why do you have the list `i`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to, as you've asked, "still iterate to the next value when that loop is entered again",  you can convert the inner loop's list to an iterator. Each item you "saw" is consumed, and you won't access it again, allowing you to continue from the same spot next time:

```
item_iter = iter(item)
for x in i:
    for y in item_iter:
        print y
        break

I
want
this
output
```

This is assuming you are indeed in a situation needing that kind of solution. Simpler one would be:

```
for x, y in zip(i, item):
    print y
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted; using an iterator for the inner loop is exactly what I'd use.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
item = ["give", "me", "free", "things"]
for x in item
    print x
```

You could also do:

```
item = ["give", "me", "free", "things"]
for x in list(enumerate(item))
    print item[x]
```

Comment: use `enumerate` not range